# "This application does'not work without javascript" in android through dialogflow iframe code

Tags: javascript, android, html, dialogflow-es

I am facing a issue while implementing web demo code of dialogflow in android but it is showing me "This application does'not work without javascript". Here is the html code i have written:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial- scale=1, user-scalable=no\"/>
    <title>Dialog</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <iframe
            id="dialog"
            allow="microphone;"
            width="350"
            height="430"
            src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/dba29fd3-8e06-4c71-a974-f2b1f1f59776">
    </iframe>
</div>
<div align="center">
    <script>
     var dialogFrame = document.getElementById("dialog");
     var dialogDocument = dialogFrame.contentWindow.document;
     document.write(dialogResponse);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works as normal html file but doesn't in android. here is the android code i have used:-

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_id);
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: @GautamBothra Can you accept as correct answer please ?

Comment: i have one more issue with dialogflow web demo. mic button is not working and not giving response in audio. Do you have any idea about that.

Comment: Please elaborate more.

Comment: <iframe
    allow="microphone;"
    width="350"
    height="430"
    src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/xyz">
</iframe>     this is the iframe provided by dialogflow for integration with web. but when i run it in android app, and try to give input by mic, mic is not taking input from mic. Although it is taking input from text/ keyboard and responding too but it is not taking input from mic neither responding from mic.

Comment: I cannot find any icon image in this link  "https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/dba29fd3-8e06-4c71-a974-f2b1f1f59776"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355341/mic-is-not-working-in-dialogflow-web-integration-with-custom-android-app

Comment: here is the link of my another question where i have explained the details. Please help me.