# Mic is not working in dialogflow web integration with custom android app

Tags: android, iframe, dialogflow-es, microphone

I am integrating my dialogflow agent with web android app but mic is not working with web integration. Although i am getting response while using text input in web demo but when i give input through mic, then neither input is recognised nor i am getting any response in my custom android app of web integration with dialogflow.
I have also allowed microphone in iframe but still it is not working.

Can anyone help me on this Please?

```
<iframe
allow="microphone;"
width="350"
height="430"
src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/dba29fd3-8e06-4c71-a974-f2b1f1f59776">
</iframe>
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: i am using google-chrome.